# Smoothening a curve in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smoothing

I am trying to form a smooth curve using data points (96 data points) using the following code. y=lol is a list containing data points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

    x = np.arange(1,97,1)
    y = lol
    def smooth(y, box_pts):
        box = np.ones(box_pts)/box_pts
        y_smooth = np.convolve(y, box, mode='same')
        
        return y_smooth
    
    
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (25,10)
    plot(x,y,'o')
    plot(x,smooth(y,12), 'r-', lw=2)
    #plot(x, smooth(y,19), 'g-', lw=2)
```

However, on the curve edges, the value of the curve drops to a very low value. How do I resolve this. I am getting a curve as below-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using mode="valid":

```
y_smooth = np.convolve(y, box, mode='valid')
```

This will remove boundary effects, but the output shape will be not be the same length as the input. See [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) for more info.

Comment: It gives an error- x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (96,) and (85,)
How do I specify the shape in this case then?

Comment: Just plot the y-values, plot(y,'o') and plot(smooth(y,12), 'r-', lw=2)